# The goal is to make my code print 5 numbers, then on another line print another 5 numbers, etc. I cant seem to do it. What do I have to add?

Tags: java, for-loop

The numbers are supposed to be the multiples of 3, with an upper limit of 30. This is pulled in through the scanner. The code print an output that looks like this:

```
3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
```

but I want it to look like this:

```
3 6 9 12 15
18 21 24 27 30
```

How would I go about doing this?

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class multiples {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int UpperLimit =  input.nextInt();
        int impoNum = UpperLimit;
        int positiveNum =  input.nextInt();
        int counter = 0;

        System.out.println("Positive Number: " + positiveNum);
        System.out.println("Upper Limit: " + UpperLimit);
        System.out.println("");

        for (int count = positiveNum; count <= UpperLimit; count += positiveNum) {
            counter++;
            System.out.print(count + " ");
            if (counter > count + impoNum) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        int Remainder = UpperLimit % positiveNum;
        if (UpperLimit % positiveNum != 0) {
            System.out.print("Remainder: " + Remainder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Accept and up vote answers if they are useful and best suits for you!

Comment: I am! it's just that I just started the account so the upvotes I give don't show lol. Really am thankful for everyone though!

Answer (score 0):

Change internal if part as below:

```
 if (counter >= impoNum)
 {
      System.out.println();
      counter = 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can change the condition to check the `counter` if its reminder 5 is 0 then add new line:

```
if (counter % 5 == 0) {
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot!